# Is it possible to override the AssetResolver test expression when using Haul?

Tags: webpack, react-native-ios

When using Haul with ReactNative, I can see that the AssetResolver class accepts options, one of which is a test regular expression to be used to select the files.

I see in some of the examples that the AssetResolver can be instantiated as a plugin in certain cases and passed these options.

Is there a proper way to import/use the Haul AssetResolver from within the webpack.haul.js to provide this configuration to the AssetResolver? It appears as though the only export from the haul package is a function to get a default config.